# Kivy fails to change label text

Tags: android, python, ios, kivy

I'm trying to create a simple script using [`Kivy`](http://kivy.org/):

```
 def __init__(self):
    super(ProvaLayout, self).__init__()
    self.cols = 2
    self.Labell = Label(text="-------------")
    self.add_widget(self.Labell)
    self.btn = Button(text="caio")
    self.add_widget(self.btn)
    def callback(self, pos, instance):
        self.Labell=Label(text="caio")
    self.btn.bind(on_pressed = callback)
```

However, the above doesn't change the text of `labell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A corrected version. Mistakes described in the comments.

```
def __init__(self):
    super(ProvaLayout, self).__init__()
    self.cols = 2
    self.Labell = Label(text="-------------")
    self.add_widget(self.Labell)
    self.btn = Button(text="caio")
    self.add_widget(self.btn)         
    def callback(instance): # single argument without self (it's a local function inside a method)
        self.Labell.text="caio"  # changing text property of existing self.Label instead of creating a new object       
    self.btn.bind(on_press = callback) # you should use on_press, not on_pressed
```